# light-weight cross-platform customizable IDE

Tags: ide, cross-platform, customization, ide-customization

what is the most light-weight IDE that provides only the bare-bones services such as a project concept, a gui and document management facilities that can be fully customized!? I know Visual Studio has some such edition but I can't remember how it's called but if you know what I mean what I am looking for is THAT (VS bare-bones) + cross-platform support.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the [Express editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/) of visual studio? They are not cross platform, but Windows only (though they work well with [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)).

I don't believe there is *any* edition of Visual Studio that is cross platform by design.

For a cross platform IDE you can try [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Comment: No I don't mean the express editions. A long time ago in a forum about a tool like Resharper I read a suggestion from someone to download a strange edition of Visual Studio that allowed full-fledged extensions whereas the express editions did not support the particual extension in question. I will google it soon and post my findings here. MonoDevelop sounds quite good suggestion for me as I am C# guy already but not so much for other devs in my team for, we are a C/C++/Fortran community. I wonder how long it will take till someone suggests Emacs :)

Comment: again: whoa google never stops amazing me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Extensibility it was called Visual Studio Shell. That's the type of thing I am looking for and as I said MonoDevelop is quite a good suggestion but I still want to hear others' suggestions.